# Firefox Mixed Content Blocker

Tags: security, http, web-applications, https

On my site served over https a user may enter a URL and preview their entered URL in an embedded iframe.

This iframe is getting blocked by Firefox 23's mixed content blocker by default. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a workaround.

Comment: The obvious (and best) solution: fix the content so that it's not mixed. There is also a button in Firefox (apparently - I've never seen it) that disables the blocker for the session, but it's not persistent. There is also a move to include a whitelist, but both the button and the whitelist are user actions.

Comment: The main problem is that the user enters the url themselves so there's no guarantee it'll be secure. I've noticed the button to disable the blocker but it won't be obvious to the users.

Comment: If the page is insecure, can you redirect to an insecure version of your site?

Comment: This isn't an option our servers serve everything over https.

Comment: that new FF 23 feature does not make sense in an intranet. I wish I could switch it off within a certain local IP address range.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Snapito! (http://snapito.com).
They have an API that works over https, so if you used their preview you would cease getting mixed content.

HTH